# How to stop Sumo Logic alerts

Tags: sumologic

How can I (force) stop receiving the Sumo Logic alerts?

I have scheduled a Sumo Logic search, and started receiving the email alerts. However, after I unscheduled it (*Run frequency* = "Never") and even deleted it, I'm still receiving these alerts. It's been over 24 hours now.

I am looking at our org's "Library"; that's where I deleted the scheduled search. Is there anywhere else I can look to see why it's still running?

Comment: I would reach out to Sumo Logic's support. If you've switched the run frequency to "never", then obviously it shouldn't ever run again. They'll be able to help you out from here. support@sumologic.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Sumologic Support, I got to the bottom of this.

In short, I had saved my scheduled search elsewhere (duplicating it) by mistake, and it was this *other* instance (of which I was unaware) that was sending the alerts.

Looking back, this is where it had gone wrong:

1. first, I created a scheduled search by running a Sumo search and clicking "Save As"; I saved it to a team folder, where it really belonged
2. some time later, I must have run the query again and clicked "Save As" again

   - this is wrong; after a query is saved once, it should be modified via the "Edit" link, not "Save As"
   - what's worse, the "Save As" dialog offers my *personal* folder as the default save location, and I must have overlooked it, thus producing a copy of my scheduled search
3. at this point, I had two identical searches scheduled: one in the team folder, and one in my personal folder (which I didn't know about); no matter how I modified the scheduled search in the team folder, even deleting it, I never stopped being alerted (because the other search was still active)

I recommend using Sumologic Support; they accessed my account, looked around, and quickly figured out what was wrong.

Comment: “what's worse, the "Save As" dialog offers my personal folder as the default save location”. Have you provide feedback to SumoLogic that their default folder should be changed to previously saved folder?

Comment: No. TBH, there are more things I struggled with in setting up my alerts (more counter-intuitive than this one) but, being new to SumoLogic, I've tried not to judge too fast. There's a fine line between diligently providing quality first-timer feedback and annoyingly complaining about a product I don't know well enough yet...

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple copies of the same query.

When you receive Alert email, it includes a link to query. Open the link and then “Edit” it, then change schedule to “Never”